# No real time data from FTX websocket

Tags: websocket, real-time-data

Is FTX websocket working right now ? I can't take real time data through it.. Can someone confirm this please? I know about the FTX bankruptcy and it is being hacked. Just want a confirmation, and if you know about alternative methods to get ftx websocket real time data plz let me know . I will attach an image what I can see when I try to connect[image: Ftx websocket error]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can confirm this. It's very unstable at this time. Even basic FTX endpoints can return 522 Connection Timed Out